OneDrive access denied error during flow list loading in power-automate-desktop
I get "access denied" when trying to load "My flows" inside the power automate desktop. The log messages shows this exception:
Microsoft.Flow.RPA.Desktop.Shared.Clients.Common.Repos.OneDrive.OneDriveClientException: Access denied

My account isn't work or educational account. I tried to login to my PowerAutomate account from more than 5 place, maybe this is because of it. Now I can't load my flows from anywhere. Also it may be related to the region. I can't find the real reason behind this issue and can't resolve it.
One strange thing is this geo value inside the logs when application tries to access the Onedrive:
{"azureRegionInfo":{"cloud":"tip0",
"geo":"unitedstates",
"region":"one-drive-environment-Region"},
"agentVersion":"2.45.00406.24170",
"executionInfo":{"contextId":0,
"is64BitProcess":true,
"processName":"PAD.Console.Host",
"sessionId":1,
"threadId":0},
"httpStatusCode":"Forbidden",

Even so my PowerAutomate account's region is GLOBAL but for Onedrive it uses the "unitedstate" geo.
I tried logout/login and changing my password too. Also I waited 2 days and issue still exists. Also I tried login with another account and it worked fine without problem. But my flows are inside my accounts and I need to access them.

I am also experiencing difficulties accessing my Power Automate flows. While I can access OneDrive with my Hotmail account , I am unable to load my flows within the Power Automate environment. I have attempted logging out and back in with my Outlook account, and i don't have that issue.
I suspect there may be an ongoing issue with the Microsoft server or maybe something relate with Hotmail maybe..
In the meantime, to run the flow, you can recover it from your local files. This involves navigating to the following directory:
C:\Users{user}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Power Automate Desktop\Console\Workspace
Please note that loading the recovered flow may take some time.

Thanks, how is it possible to run the flow through the local files?

I don't think you can. you should create a new outlook account . Many people issue with hotmail, gmail etc .but outlook account still work fine.

please check my post here to recover local file: link

this issue has been resolved by MS on the backend. you'll need to use the method above to restore your flows
